# Не заносятся параметры в базу данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

У меня есть код.

```
public class RegistrationDataBase {
private String name;
private String password;
String urlDB = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/notebook";
String passwordDB = "notebook";
String loginDB = "notebook";
public RegistrationDataBase(String name, String password){
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
}
public void connectToData(){
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    try{
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(urlDB, loginDB, passwordDB);
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into public.twits(name, pass) values(?,?)");
        preparedStatement.setString(1,name);
        preparedStatement.setString(2,password);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

В коде выше я подключаю базу, и пытаюсь вставить в таблицу имя и пароль пользователя. Далее сервлет:

```
public class RegistrationInDataBaseServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    RegistrationDataBase registrationDataBase = new RegistrationDataBase(request.getParameter("name"), request.getParameter("pass"));
    registrationDataBase.connectToData();
}
}
```

И сам коннекшн:

```
public class RegistrationInTwit extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RegistrationInDataBaseServlet");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        printWriter.print("name");
        printWriter.print("=");
        printWriter.print(URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("name")));
        printWriter.print('&');
        printWriter.print("pass");
        printWriter.print('=');
        printWriter.print(URLEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("pass")));
        printWriter.close();
        connection.getInputStream();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("GoodIn.jsp");
    requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

XML:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationInDataBaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ohNo.RegistrationInDataBaseServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationTwit</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ohNo.RegistrationInTwit</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationInDataBaseServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegistrationInDataBaseServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationTwit</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegistrationInTwit</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE twits
(
name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
pass VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
);
```

JSP:

```
<body>
<form action="RegistrationInTwit" method="POST">
Введите имя: <input type="text" name="name" />
Введите пароль: <input type="text" name="pass" />
<input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" />
</form>
</body>
```

Не могу понять в чем дело, руинится на первом этапе, при доблавении в базу нового юзера, то есть в таблице новые данные не появляются. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, глаз замелен уже.

Comment: покажите ошибку, что выдает?

Comment: Спасибо за оперативность, ошибку уже исправила)

Answer (score 1):

Есть догадки:

- поле id не заполняется, а без него запись не создаётся - попробовать SERIAL
- названия полей name или pass являются зарезервированными словами - переименовать
- название таблицы, возможно, нужно писать без префикса public - убрать из запроса
- тип VARCHAR выдаёт ошибку при попадании в строку кириллицы - заменить на NVARCHAR
- размерность полей мала - увеличить

Надеюсь, что-нибудь поможет.

Comment: id у меня заполняется автоматически. 
Так, переименую. 
public видимо особенность моей интеледжи, потому что без паблика таблицу она не видит.
Заменю. 
Хорошо, попробую. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Кстати, прошло и без public перед таблицей, спасибо вам за наводку!

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за данные ответы, ошибку исправила сама. Если кто-то столкнется с подобным, и будет целую ночь мучится также как я, то кроме вышеперечисленных ответов, проверьте правильно написания Class.forName("ваш драйвер")
Также, в обязательном порядке, (если работаете в интеледжи) в папке WEB-INF создаете папочку lib, куда вставляете скаченный драйвер. Все работает. 
Еще раз всех благодарю.